# Update a custom component with standard component events

Tags: lightning-web-components, publish-subscribe

Can we listen for standard or toast events on LWC with a pubsub e.g. for the purpose of using a standard component to update a custom component?

Comment: Lwc works onxxx={handleEvent} have you tried with that?

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty for standard components that are abstracted. I can listen in on custom components with custom event handlers and attributes or pub sub. I just don't know how to do it for standard components on a lightning page.